# See nothing after adding label to scrollview

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add label to scrollview in swift but it doesn't works for me, here my code:

```
let messageLbl: UILabel = UILabel()
messageLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width-60, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
messageLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
messageLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
messageLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
messageLbl.numberOfLines = 0
messageLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neuse", size: 17)
messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
messageLbl.text = "myTextGoesHere"
messageLbl.sizeToFit()
messageLbl.layer.zPosition = 20
messageLbl.frame.origin.x = (self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width - self.messageX) - messageLbl.frame.size.width
messageLbl.frame.origin.y = self.messageY
self.resultsScrollView.addSubview(messageLbl)
```

But I see nothing when I run my app:

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Check your scroll view frame

Comment: @RakeshaShastri what do you mean, what should I check?

Comment: What does `print (messageLbl.frame.origin.x)` give you?

Comment: @Carpsen90 it gives `499.5`

Comment: @trycatch that's too far to the right, you need to fix `messageLbl.frame.origin.x = ...`

Comment: @Carpsen90 you are right, it works now, thank you!, post as answer if u want

Answer (score 0):

If you "*see nothing when [you] run [your] app*" that doesn't mean it doesn't exist in the hierarchy of your views. Debug your code by printing `messageLbl.frame.origin.x` and check if you get a value bigger than the width of your screen.

Adjusting the code in this line will do the trick:

```
messageLbl.frame.origin.x = (self.resultsScrollView.frame.size.width - self.messageX) - messageLbl.frame.size.width
```